# CakePHP authentication - Can't login with form

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.1

I'm using email_address as username for a simple login.

```
public $components = array(
                'DebugKit.Toolbar', 
                'Session',
                'Auth' => array(
                    'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index'),
                    'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'),
                    'loginAction' => array(
                                'controller' => 'users',
                                'action' => 'signin',
                            ),
                    'authenticate' => array(
                                'Form' => array(
                                    'fields' => array('username' => 'email_address')
                                )
                            )
                ),
            );
```

I have explicitly told cake to use email_address as username

```
public function signin(){
        if(! $this->Auth->user()){

            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'));
                }
            }
        }else{
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
    }
```

I have verified that my post data is being sent through from the form

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form-inputs">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Existing Customers</legend>
            <p>Sign in to continue</p>
            <ul class="form short">
                <li>
                    <label for="username">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="username" id="username">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
                </li>
                <li class="no-label checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me">
                    <label for="remember_me">Remember me</label>
                </li>
                <li class="no-label">
                    <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
                    <a href="/">Forgotten your password?</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

I can't successfully log in. The user does exist, and the passwords are hashed when created, like so:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        if (isset($this->data['User']['password'])) {
            $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Can't see where i am going wrong, any ideas?

Comment: `Can't see where i am going wrong` You aren't using the form helper.

Comment: Right you are, silly mistake - name of inputs were wrong (data[user][email_address])